# @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class) and PowerMockRule

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

In my code I am using `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` at class level and in test class I have to use `PowermockRule`

Code is something like this

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ClassName
{
    @Mock
    Class c1;

    @Rule
    PowerMockRule rule=new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    setUp()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    //Test Case here
}
```

It gives me
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

I am not sure if we are not allowed to initialize that in setUp method.

I tried using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` but that is also giving me matcher error.
**`Using Mockito 1.9 and PowerMock 1.5`**

Can you please help me find out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code here doesn't compile. Could you fix the compile errors first?

Comment: code is now corrected

Comment: Are you using Mockito 1.9.0 or 1.9.5? Because according to the wiki  PowerMock 1.5 only works with Mockito 1.9.5: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Answer (score -1):

I hit exactly the same matcher problem when using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` (JUnitParamsRunner.class) approach.  I keep try and error and at last I found it works when I add `@PrepareForTest` annotation under each individual method instead of class level only.

Hope this helps.